# I can´t set url image in BottomNavigationView Android

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, bottomnavigationview

i´ve got an image profile from Facebook/Twitter SDKs and i want to show as an item it in BottomNavigationView.
[this is the desired result with social image profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmBJG.png)
I saved profile picture like Bitmap and i try to load it into menuItem but i got this result:

[this is the ugly result i´ve got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFL9L.png)

I have tried too many ways like:

1. Load it directly in MenuItem like this:

   MenuItem menuItem = bottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.profile_view);
       menuItem.setIcon(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), //Bitmap from url);
2. Create an ActionLayout in Menu and load the image into ImageView in ActionLayout.
3. Use another libraries for BottomNavigationView like:

   ```
   com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation
   ```

But nothing works fine, i appreciate your help!

Thanks!

Comment: just an fyi, it is against the Android Material Design Support guides to do that; all menu items in a BottomNavigationView should be consistent in style: https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-usage

Comment: oh i know, thanks it should be a flat drawable icon like the others, it's just a design i should preferably follow in my job, so i just want to discard all possibilities i´ve got